# Is there a word we can use to refer to big clusters of clouds?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word we can use to refer to big clusters of clouds, attached or unattached? I am thinking there might be a word, but I've never really heard of words related to cloud being used in any book I've ever read. I keep seeing words related to a type of clouds, but not related to a group or cluster.

Comment: [What is the collective noun for “clouds”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/44214/291924).

Answer (score 1):

There are many choices.
[English corpora](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/)
If you search there with the phrases
**a NOUN of clouds**  or
**the NOUN of clouds**
you will see many options (ranked by frequency).
These are a few from the first page: mass, sea, line, blanket, layer, canopy et al.

Answer (score 1):

Jack's answer is good (and useful for poets), but the most idiomatic noun for a mass of clouds is **bank**.
The OED (Oxford English Dictionary) includes a sub-entry for **cloud-bank**, citing one J. Hodgson (1858): "A cloud-bank that seemed to rest on the sea."